# Can't find project or library, reference with FileSystemObject with Excel VBA on Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

In code that I have I reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime library, to make use of the `FileSystemObject`. Of course this won't work on a Mac. Therefore my first sub is to determine what OS the machine the code is being executed on is running, and to stop execution when this is a Mac:

```
Sub BezemResultaat()
    If Left(Application.OperatingSystem, 3) = "Mac" Then
        fout = MsgBox("Deze macro werkt alleen op een windows PC vooralsnog.", vbOKOnly, "Fout!")
        If fout = vbYes Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Call GetData
    End If
End Sub
```

In the `GetData` sub I reference to the FSO. I thought this would work, but on a Mac this errors out due to a missing library.

Is there a different approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [compiler constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/compiler-constants) and [late binding](https://superuser.com/questions/615463/how-to-avoid-references-in-vba-early-binding-vs-late-binding).

Function to check if you are on a Mac with compiler constant (credit to [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac001.htm))

```
Function IsMac() As Boolean
#If Mac Then
    IsMac = True
#End If
End Function
```

Code to control program flow:

```
Sub BezemResultaat()
    If IsMac Then
        MsgBox "etc"
    Else
        GetData
    End If
End Sub
```

`GetData` sub:

```
Sub GetData()

    Dim objFso As Object

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") '<-- should not be a compile time error

    ' do your stuff

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints Robin, however this doesn't solve the problem. Still when I call `BezemResultaat()` I get the error.

Comment: Is it a different error - I'm thinking you no longer get the compile time error but a runtime error ?

Comment: On a side note, it's completely horrible that the debugger just lists the first line of code on a compile error...

Comment: I just edited the answer to remove the `()` from `GetData()` and just have `GetData` which was a silly typo. Can you try again?

Comment: So maybe if you just try with `If Not IsMac Then GetData` and see if that works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147246/discussion-between-luuklag-and-robin-mackenzie).

Comment: You ofcourse need to remove the checkmark in the list of libraries.